# Rails 3.1 - Using Scopes to Find Unenrolled Students

Tags: scope, nested, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
# student.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses

# course.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :students
```

I'm trying to create a scope in the students model that will check if they are enrolled in a course.

The best I've come up with is:

```
scope :unenrolled, where(Student.courses.count => 0)
```

But then I get the error message

> undefined method `courses'

Anybody offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright then. So here's your code:

```ruby
scope :unenrolled, where(Student.courses.count => 0)
```

The first problem here is the thing that's causing the error: You're calling the *instance* method `courses` on the *class* `Student`. As the name implies, you can only call an instance method on an instance of a class, not on the class itself. For example:

```ruby
jim = Student.find(123)
jims_courses = jim.courses
```

But here's the kicker: When you call `scope` you're in the *class* context, i.e. the code isn't inside an instance method, so it gets called when your model is first declared. There's no instance at that time so you can't just call `courses` like you would from within one of `Student`'s instance methods.

But that's kind of moot since you've slightly misunderstood how `where` works. The argument(s) you give to `where` are supposed to be *conditions* that correspond to what you would put after `WHERE` in an SQL query. For example `where(:eye_color => 'brown')` will be turned into an SQL `WHERE` clause like `WHERE eye_color = 'brown'`. `:eye_color => 'brown'` is just a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) with the key `:eye_color` whose value is `'brown'`. Calling a function on the left side of `=>` doesn't make sense unless the function returns the name of a column/attribute in your model that ActiveRecord will understand.

So now let's figure out what you *should* do. If you were writing an SQL query it would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT `students`.*, COUNT(`courses_students`.*) AS `courses_count`
  FROM `students`
  JOIN `courses_students` ON `students`.`id` = `courses_students`.`student_id`
 WHERE `courses_count` = '0'
 GROUP BY `courses_students`.`student_id`;
```

This translates roughly to an ActiveRecord query like this:
    Student.joins(:courses).  // AR automatically joins `courses` though `courses_students`
      select('students.*, COUNT(courses.*) AS courses_count').
      where('courses_count = 0').
      group('id')

And you can plunk that directly into your scope:

```ruby
scope :unenrolled,  joins(:courses).
                    select('students.*, COUNT(courses.*) AS courses_count').
                    where('courses_count = 0').
                    group('courses.course_id')
```

*Note:* These queries are a bit off-the-cuff and may require a bit of tweaking. The easiest way to build complicated ActiveRecord queries is by entering them directly into the Rails console until you get the results you want.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Now THIS is why I love the SO community! Thanks so much for the help, I understand this so much better than before!

I can see the logic in the query but it's throwing an exception still.

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: courses.course_id: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, courses.course_id AS courses_course_id FROM "students" INNER JOIN "courses_students" ON "courses_students"."student_id" = "students"."id" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "courses_students"."course_id" WHERE (courses_count = 0) GROUP BY courses.course_id ORDER BY "students".id desc
`

Comment: SQL just isn't my thing really :(

Comment: Okay, this is quite confusing, even still I get the following exception `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: courses_count: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, courses.id AS courses_id FROM "students" INNER JOIN "courses_students" ON "courses_students"."student_id" = "students"."id" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "courses_students"."course_id" WHERE (courses_count = 0) GROUP BY courses.id ORDER BY "students".id desc`.
Perhaps you could also help me to understand WHY I get this error, as well as possible solutions?

Comment: You changed the column alias (after `AS`) from `courses_count` to `count_all` but then didn't change `courses_count` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Nope, I'm haven't changed the alias at all?
`scope :waiting_list,
  joins(:courses).
  select('students.*, COUNT(courses.*) AS courses_count').
  where('courses_count = 0').
  group('courses.id')`
Could this have anything to do with the fact I'm using a SQLite3 db?

Comment: No, it's just that I don't have your actual app so I wrote the code blind. You may have to solve this one yourself, just tear it down to the smallest bit and build it back up piece by working piece.